# boost::regex_search - boost kills my brain cells, again

Tags: c++, windows, regex, boost

Good programmers keep simple things easy right?
And it's not like the boost documentation makes your life less uneasy...

All I want is an implementation for:

```
// fulfils the function of a regex matching where the pattern may match a
// substring instead of the entire string
bool search( std::string, std::string, SomeResultType )
```

So it can be used as in:

```
std::string     text, pattern;
SomeResultsType match;

if( search( text, pattern, match ) )  
{
   std::string result      = match[0];

   if( match[1].matched )
      // where this is the second capture group, not recapturing the same group
      std::string secondMatch = match[1];

}
```

I want my client code not to be bothered with templates and iterators... I know, I'm a wuss. After peering for an hour over the template spaghetti in the boost docs for doing something so simple, I feel like my productivity is seriously getting hampered and I don't feel like I've learned anything from it.

boost::regex_match does it pretty simple with boost::cmatch, except that it only matches the whole string, so I've been adapting all my patterns to match the whole strings, but I feel that it is a dirty hack and would prefer some more proper solution. If I would have known it would take this long, I would have stuck with regex_match

Also welcome, a copy of *Reading boost documentation for dummies*

Next week in *Keep it simple and easy with boost*, function binders! No, just kidding, I wouldn't do that to anyone.

Thanks for all help

Comment: Perhaps your systems already are equipped with the POSIX regex functions? Try `man regexec`.

Comment: I use windows, and would prefer not to have to install another third party lib for just regex as boost already has this.

Comment: There is an example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/captures.html.  It is not as simple as you would like it to be, but it is still understandable.  Maybe python will give you what you want more easily

Comment: @stefaanv: The sample is for repeated captures, which is not what I need and uses regex_match, for which matches only the entire string unless i use the hack mentioned above... Creating a python dll just to have a userfriendly interface to regex from C++ is not exactly my understanding of: "keep simple things easy".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want regex_search: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html

Probably this overload is the one you want:
bool regex_search(const basic_string& s,
                  match_results::const_iterator, Allocator>& m,
                  const basic_regex& e,
                  match_flag_type flags = match_default);

That seems to match what you wanted - SomeResultsType is smatch, and you need to convert your pattern to a regex first.

Comment: and all the code that makes any use of the captured results ends up looking like this:  m[std::string(what[5].first, what[5].second) + std::string(what[6].first, what[6].second)] = what[5].first - file.begin(); 
Taken from boost docs. 
And that is kind of what I try to avoid. And there is no easy way to hide that inside of the function implementation of "search()", unless you know a handy way to convert match_results<typename basic_string<charT, ST,SA>::const_iterator,Allocator>& in boost::cmatch&

Comment: Why don't you simply wrap the boost function call with a function of your own that does the search and returns the results by reference to a vector?

Comment: @Dakota: that is actually not such a bad idea. Especially since I would only have to write it once ever... A vector would lose some of the functionality of match_results, but I don't think I'm going to need that alot anyways.

Comment: std::string(what[6].first, what[6].second) seems overly complicated.
what[6] has an implicit conversion to std::string, or you can if you need to explicitly call what[6].str().

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use the [.NET Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx):

Example (copied from the linked page):

```
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;
int main()
{
   // Define a regular expression for repeated words.
   Regex^ rx = gcnew Regex( "\\b(?<word>\\w+)\\s+(\\k<word>)\\b",static_cast<RegexOptions>(RegexOptions::Compiled | RegexOptions::IgnoreCase) );

   // Define a test string.        
   String^ text = "The the quick brown fox  fox jumped over the lazy dog dog.";

   // Find matches.
   MatchCollection^ matches = rx->Matches( text );

   // Report the number of matches found.
   Console::WriteLine( "{0} matches found.", matches->Count );

   // Report on each match.
   for each (Match^ match in matches)
   {
      String^ word = match->Groups["word"]->Value;
      int index = match->Index;
      Console::WriteLine("{0} repeated at position {1}", word, index);   
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort, but I prefer not to use .NET, because it is not portable and also because even on windows as a user I hate their side by side policy. It's not like your app depends on just another dll being shipped with it. Boost doesn't even require an extra dll. I prefer not to install another third party lib for something boost already (does/should do), but I would use any third party lib before I would turn to .NET